# Лучшие практики развертывания и работы с ФИАС

Tags: база-данных

**Предыстория**

У нас есть SQL Server 2014 в котором мы ведем множество БД. В базе клиентов для хранения адреса (область/край, город/пгт, улица) мы используем модифицированный КЛАДР. Модификация заключается в добавлении к адресу чего то типа *дивизиона* (например Москва и область это Центр, Питер - северо-запад и т.д.).

Т.к. КЛАДР уступает место более полному ФИАС мы хотим развернуть новую БД для хранения этих данных. И плавно перейти на ФИАС. Для извлечения и обновления данных будет использоваться API, написанное на PHP.

**Вопрос**

Возможно вопрос слишком общий и заключается в поиске некоего мануала, но все же я надеюсь получить более-менее развернутый ответ. Я пробовал искать *инструкции* по развёртыванию, но не нашел ничего стоящего.

- Пригодны ли xsd схемы (идущие в комплекте с xml) для создания таблиц в SQL server?
- Для поиска адресов используется иерархический тип данных? Если да, то насколько он быстр в 2014 версии сервера?
- Возможно для хранения и работы с ФИАС лучше использовать другую СУБД. Если да, то какую и почему?
- Если вы занимались развертыванием ФИАС, пожалуйста, поделитесь опытом: с чем столкнулись, какие узкие места в работе с этой БД и т.д.

Comment: Если вдруг ещё не гуглили http://wiki.gis-lab.info/w/%D0%A4%D0%98%D0%90%D0%A1

Comment: @Sergey спасибо за ссылку! читал эту wiki в 2015, видимо с тех пор ничего нового не придумали/не написали :\